# weka and visual graphs

Tags: user-interface, visualization, weka

Here is my situation. I've been given testing and training data. Now, I'm supposed to run weka to run various machine learning algorithms. The catch is that I need to also produce graphs (the exact instructions are: "At the very least you should include graphs that show performance on both training and test data as a function of training size"). So, to narrow down my question, let's say that I working on decision trees (specifically J48 algorithm), and I need to produce graphs. How do I do this?

How do I do this? I have found absolute zero help from using Google. I would LIKE to be able to not have to give up the gui when using weka.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any weka functions to do this. You may use any graphic/chart utility like, matlab,excel,R for this purpose. What you need to do is following. Lets say you have a training dataset of 10.000 instances and test set of 2000 instances.

```
TrainingDataSetSizePercent TrainingDataSetSizePercent TestDataSetSize Accuracy    Accuracy
                                                                     OnTraining    OnTest
     %5                            500                    2000          %80          %60
     %10                          1000                    2000          %82          %70
     %20                          2000                    2000          %84          %71
     %50                          5000                    2000          %85          %72
     %100                        10000                    2000          %87          %81
```

give this numbers to matlab as following code.

```
 accuracy_scores = [ 500 80 60;1000 82 70; 2000 84 71; 5000 85 72; 10000 87 81];
 plot(accuracy_scores(:,1),accuracy_scores(:,2),accuracy_scores(:,1),accuracy_scores(:,3))
```

This code will give you following chart[image: example chart]